# Proof of Proposition on Limits 

Tags: real-analysis

I need help proving the following proposition. Thank you for any help you can give me.

> Let $S \subset \mathbb R$ be a nonempty bounded set. Then there exist monotone sequences $\{ x_n \}$ and $\{ y_n \}$ such that $x_n, y_n \in S$ and
>   $$ \sup S = \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n  \ \ \ \ \ \text{ and } \ \ \ \ \  \inf S = \lim_{n \to \infty} y_n .$$

Thank you again.

Comment: @Steve,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Convergence_of_a_monotone_sequence_of_real_numbers , and use the fact that if there is supremum(infimum) it must be unique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT. Show that for each $n$, there exists some $y_n \in S$ such that
$$
\inf S \leq y_n \leq \inf S + \frac{1}{n}.
$$
Show that the sequence $\{ y_n \}$ converges to $\inf S$. Can you take it from here?

As defined, the sequence $y_n$ is not guaranteed to be monotonic, but this can be easily fixed. Be sure to take care of this in the proof.

Comment: I'll take all the help I can get thank you. I have the gist of it for the most part I believe

Comment: That's what I figured when I was doing it on my own, thank you for all the help. I have shown that, again thank you

Comment: @Steve I don't get you said. Are you able to complete it or do you want further help?